# How to pass empty list via python input() function

Tags: python, algorithm, exception, input, binary-search-tree

```
def binarysearch(arr,n):
arr.sort()
while(1):
    i=0
    mid = len(arr)//2
    if(len(arr)==0):
        return False
    elif(len(arr)==1):
        return True if arr[0]==n else False
    else:
        if n==arr[mid]:
            return True
        elif n<arr[mid]:
            arr = arr[:mid]
        else:
            arr = arr[mid:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
arr = list(map(int,input().split(',')))
n   = int(input("Enter the number to search :"))
status,i = binarysearch(arr,n)

if status:

print("Found element " + str(n))
else:
    print("Not Found!!!")
```

I'm new to python.. 
In this program.. is it possible to pass empty list via user input()..

because.. when i've not given anything or just ',' while giving user input for 'arr' in above case,
it is showing Value error..
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: `"".split(",") == [""]`. Add logic to handle that empty case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe or just catch the exception and just say "the list isn't in the right format or empty"...

Comment: Thanks for your help.. May be we can initailize arr to [] while handling Value Error exception?? by checking if arr is not created properly

Answer (score 2):

AS mentioned by @Jon Clements, use a try/except block :

" easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"

```
try:
    arr = list(map(int,input().split(',')))
    n   = int(input("Enter the number to search :"))
    status,i = binarysearch(arr,n)
except ValueError:
   raise ValueError("The list isn't in the right format or empty")

if status:
   print("Found element " + str(n))
else:
    print("Not Found!!!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining `input` with other functions almost always makes your code more complicated than it needs to be. Get the input first, handle an empty input, and then the rest of your code can proceed under the assumption that the input is *not* empty. In general, input is handled in 3 steps: *getting* the input, *validating* the input, and *using* the input.

In the following, each block of code either verifies an expected property,
or exits the program with an error message.

```
# Get a non-empty input
data = input("Enter a comma-separate list of integers: ")  # Get arr
if not data:    # Validate arr, part 1
   print("No data")
   sys.exit(1)

# Split the comma-separated input into integers
arr = data.split(",")
try:
    arr = [int(x) for x in arr]  # Validate arr, part 2
except ValueError:
    print("Non-integer data found in {}".format(data))
    sys.exit(1)

# Get the search term
data = input("Enter the number to search: ")  # Get n
try:
    n = int(data)  # Validate int
except ValueError:
    print("Non-integer search term: {}".format(data))
    sys.exit(1)

# Use arr and n
status, i = binarysearch(arr, n)

if status:
    print("Found element {}".format(n))
else:
    print("Not Found!!!")
```